# How to check if value in field is decimal and not string (DATASTAGE)?

Tags: datastage

How to check if value in field is decimal and not string (DATASTAGE) ?
I am using with Datastage Version 8.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `IsValid()` with the 'decimal' sub-type on the incoming string.

```
If IsValid("decimal" , in.value_string ) Then in.value_tring Else SetNull()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Alpha & num function inside transformer which gives you whether the given value contains only alphabets.
If alpha(column) is 1 then its purely alphabetical.
Else check if Num(column) is 1, if this true then it is purely a number.

Reference to official doc-https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZJPZ_11.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ft.usage.doc/topics/r_deeref_String_Functions.html